# Use index of a list of data.frames to apply a function in certain elements of a data frame

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` that looks like this:

```
>df

  A B   C  P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6
1 a 1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.4 0.2 0.1 0.4
2 b 1 0.2 0.1 0.4 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.2
3 c 1 0.4 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.4
4 d 2 0.1 0.1 0.7 0.5 0.1 0.7 0.1
5 e 2 0.5 0.7 0.5 0.1 0.7 0.1 0.5
6 f 2 0.7 0.5 0.5 0.7 0.1 0.7 0.1
7 g 3 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.5
8 h 3 0.2 0.2 0.1 0.5 0.2 0.2 0.5
9 i 3 0.5 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.5 0.2
```

And a list of data.frames similar to this one:

```
list.1 <- list(data.frame(AA=c("a","b","c","d")), 
             data.frame(BB=c("e","f")), 
             data.frame(CC=c("a","b","i")), 
             data.frame(DD=c("d","e","f","g")))
```

Besides, I have this function:

```
Fisher.test <- function(p) {
  Xsq <- -2*sum(log(p), na.rm=T)
  p.val <- 1-pchisq(Xsq, df = 2*length(p))
  return(p.val)
}
```

I would like to select in `df` those values of df$A that correspond to each data.frame in the list and compute `Fisher.test` for *P1...P6*. The way I was doing it is merging `df` with `list.1` and then apply `Fisher.method` to each `data.frame` in the list:

```
func <- function(x,y){merge(x,y, by.x=names(x)[1], by.y=names(y)[1])}

ll <- lapply(list.1, func, df)

ll.fis <- lapply(ll, FUN=function(i){apply(i[,4:9],2,Fisher.test)})
```

This works but my real data is huge, so I think that a different approach could use the index of elements of `list.1[1]` to calculate `Fisher.test` in `df` storing the result, then use the index of `list.1[2]` and calculate `Fisher.test` and so on. In this way, the merging would be avoided because all the calculations are made over `df`, also, the RAM resources would be also minimised with this approach. However, I have no clue how to achieve this. Perhaps a for loop?

Thanks

Comment: data.table is your friend here.  setkey to `A`, then use `lapply(list.1, function(x) DT[.(x), <expression>])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leveraging data.table here is helpful since you can easily subset your data using `.( )` syntax and extremely fast, especially with large data compared to working with, say `subset`

```
library(data.table)

# convert to data.table, setting the key to the column `A`
DT <- data.table(df, key="A")

p.col.names <- paste0("P", 1:6)
results <- lapply(list.1, function(ll)
        DT[.(ll)][, lapply(.SD, Fisher.test), .SDcols=p.col.names] )

results
```

#### side note

You might want to fix the names of `list.1` so that the results form `lapply` are properly named

```
# fix the names, helpful for the lapply
names(list.1) <- lapply(list.1, names)
```

#### results:

```
$AA
           P1        P2        P3       P4        P5      P6
1: 0.04770305 0.1624142 0.2899578 0.029753 0.1070376 0.17549

$BB
          P1        P2        P3        P4        P5        P6
1: 0.7174377 0.5965736 0.2561482 0.2561482 0.2561482 0.1997866

$CC
          P1       P2       P3         P4        P5        P6
1: 0.0317663 0.139877 0.139877 0.05305057 0.1620897 0.2189595

$DD
         P1        P2        P3        P4        P5        P6
1: 0.184746 0.4246214 0.2704228 0.1070376 0.3215871 0.1519672
```

Comment: is the Fisher.test applied by column? the function should return only one pvalue for column....

Comment: @user2380782, please see the edit.  (the original response was applying per column per value in A.  The edited version is per column.)

Comment: Ricardo, I tried to modify your code above just to merge data frames in a list, but I most likely did something wrong (I'm just starting with `data.table`). Would you take a look (https://github.com/abnova/diss-floss/blob/master/analysis/sem-models/floss-success-v2-flat/mergeTest.R; lines 160-161)?

Comment: Sorry Aleksandr, I took a peak at your code, but it is not immidiately obvious, and I regretfully do not have time to sift through all of your code. I would suggest trying to zero in on the issue yourself and then posting a follow up (new) question here on SO