# Merge with allow.cartasian=TRUE results in too many observations

Tags: r, memory, merge, data.table

I want to merge 2 data frames (`data1` and `data2`). Both initially contain around 35 million observations (around 2GB each).

I removed the duplicates from `data2`. I would need to keep the duplicates in `data 1`, as I wish to use them for further calculations per observation in `data1`.

I initially get the well documented error:

> Check for duplicate key values in `i`, each of which join to the same group in `x` over and over again. If that's ok, try including `j` and dropping `by` (by-without-by) so that `j` runs for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with `allow.cartesian=TRUE`. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.

As a solution (I looked at several topics, such [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204859/error-while-merging-data-frames-using-data-table-package), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610562/merging-data-tables-uses-more-than-10-gb-ram), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087358/why-is-allow-cartesian-required-at-times-when-when-joining-data-tables-with-dupl)), I included `allow.cartesian=TRUE`, but now I run into memory issues. Also, for a subset it works, but it gives me more observations than I wish (`data1` now has 50 million observations, although is specify `all.x=TRUE`).

My code is:

```
#Remove duplicates before merge
data2 <- unique(data2)

#Merge
require(data.table)
data1 <- merge(data1, data2, by="ID", all.x=TRUE, allow.cartesian=TRUE)
```

Any advice on how to merge this, is very welcome.

Comment: Could you please specify the type of join you are trying to achieve with the merge?  It's not likely that you actually want a cartesian merge.  It's a cross-product.  You're running out of memory because the result would be in the order of 35M^2 data points.  See http://www.dofactory.com/Images/sql-joins.png

Comment: I would need a left join. If I try without the allow.cartesian, I get an error message ("Check for duplicate...", as mentioned in the post above)

Comment: examples not reproducible, read how to ask questions on r tag

Answer (score 1):

In order to do a left join, the merge statement needs to understand which column you are using as the "key" or "index" for the join.  If you have duplicate column names that are used as the key/index, it doesn't know what to do and gives that error.  Further, it needs to know what to do if columns are being joined that have the same name as existing columns.

The solution is to temporarily rename the key/index column in your left (data1) dataset  As a general rule, having duplicate column names is "bad" in R because it will confuse a lot of functions.  Many functions silently call `make.unique()` to de-duplicate column names to avoid confusion.

If you have duplicate `ID` columns in `data1` change them with `colnames(data1) <- make.unique(colnames(data1))`, which will set them to `ID.1`, `ID.2`, etc.  Then do your merge (make sure to specify `by.x="ID.1", by.y="ID"` because of the rename.  By default, duplicate columns that are merged will be appended with `.y` although you can specify the suffix with the `suffixes=` option [(See Merge helpfile for details)](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html)

Lastly, it's worth noting that the `merge()` function in the `data.table` package tends to be a lot faster than the base `merge()` function with similar syntax.  See[page 47 of the data.table manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf).